# Identity Server 4- Setting the Access Token lifetime

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I am using Identity Server 4 with my ASP.NET Core MVC application. It is working fine. And then I tried to set the access token and the identity token lifetime with the following code.

```
//AccessTokenLifetime = new TimeSpan(2,0,0).Seconds,  /*This is not working*/
AccessTokenLifetime = 7200,  /* This is setting the life time correctly */
```

When I check the '[Clients]' table in the database, the AccessTokenLifeTime is set to 0 (if TimeSpan(2,0,0) is used). But if I assign the integer 7200 directly then it sets the access token lifetime correctly.

Is there any reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't test the actual value, because that is 0. You should use TotalSeconds instead.

```
AccessTokenLifetime = new TimeSpan(2,0,0).TotalSeconds
```

Comment: Yes, that's my mistake. I didn't realize the difference correctly. Thanks for pointing out.